# Java Trouble compiling maxmind geoip LookupService class

Tags: java, class, geoip, maxmind

I wonder if some one can please help as I am struggling to compile maxmind.geoip.LookupService.java

I have downloaded geoip-api-1.2.10.jar for inclusion in WEB-INF\lib and I have referenced it in my classes path, but it just won't compile.

I have compiled the following successfully so I'm a bit at a loss:

```
com.maxmind.geoip.Country
com.maxmind.geoip.DatabaseInfo
com.maxmind.geoip.Location
com.maxmind.geoip.Region
com.maxmind.geoip.timeZone
```

Can't seem to find a full set of compiled java classes for com.maxmind.geoip, any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by downloading the latest java files from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/ unpacked the folder and then opened a command prompt and typed the following:

```
cd source/com/maxmind/geoip/
javac *.java
```

I'm using jdk1.6.0_34 and all classes compiled with no errors.

I copied the com.maxmind.geoip folder to \WEB-INF\classes and downloaded geoip-api-1.2.10.jar and placed that in the WEB-INF\lib folder.

Finally I download GeoIP.dat from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ and placed it in a new folder called GeoIP under webapps so that all my applications can use it.

The following code is to obtain the country code from a users IP Address:

```
import com.maxmind.geoip.*;
import java.io.IOException;

class CountryLookupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String dir = "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/GeoIP";
        String dbfile = dir + sep + "GeoIP.dat"; 

        LookupService cl = new LookupService(dbfile,LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

        System.out.println(cl.getCountry("151.38.39.114").getCode());
        System.out.println(cl.getCountry("151.38.39.114").getName());
        System.out.println(cl.getCountry("12.25.205.51").getName());
        System.out.println(cl.getCountry("64.81.104.131").getName());
        System.out.println(cl.getCountry("200.21.225.82").getName());

        cl.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
    }
}
```

Hope this proves useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MaxMind dev site](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/), the API is available on the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.maxmind.geoip%22). You shouldn't need to compile anything unless you downloaded the source package.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm not using Mavern, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download a Jar file called [geoIP-api](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.maxmind.geoip%22%20AND%20a%3A%22geoip-api%22) from this link to maven repository,In case you haven't downloaded the other Jar files from go this [geoIP2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.maxmind.geoip2%22%20AND%20a%3A%22geoip2%22) also don't forget to download the **.DAT** file from [geoIP.dat](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/). Then add the files to your project class path from **project** **properties** and then **libraries** finally **add Jar** in **netbeans**.

Now use this code:

```
    public String IpGeoLocation(String IP) {
        try {
            String dbfile = "C:\\Users\\User Name \\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IP Tools\\resources/GeoIP.dat";
            String location = "";
            LookupService cl = new LookupService(dbfile, LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
            location = cl.getCountry(IP).getName() + " " + cl.getCountry(IP).getCode();
            cl.close();
            return location;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                           return "Error";
        }
    }
```

I was able to find the country and country code only !!